# Why is my Media query range not working correctly?

Tags: css, media-queries

Fairly new at media queries and i have set a query to activate at a max-width of 812px.

Here is my code

```
@media(max-width: 812px) { 
.paymentInformationContainer .right button {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 0px 6px;
}

div textarea {
    width: 175px;
}
```

}`

When resizing the responsive chrome window the float does not activate until 731px (image 2). However, when I am using Chrome's device toolbar to imitate using it on an iPad (image 1) (768px) it works just fine.

[image: Ipad view]

[image: Responsive View]

Comment: Try to add min-width different values and see how it react it may be a bug in chrome responsive dev tool

Comment: i've tried that as well but it just seems to be a dead spot even if i resize the window without being in the inspector tool it specifically does not work in that one little range (892px-806px) which should be covered with the "max-width: 892px" (which i tried changing it too) if i'm correct. I'm going to cry if its like a really small fix lol